# How to explain difference between "import my_module" and "from my_module import my_str"?

Tags: python, module, python-import

How would you describe what is going on in the following code?

my_module.py :

```
my_dict = { "key": "default value" }
my_str = "default"
```

Python interpreter:

```
>>> from my_module import my_dict, my_str
>>> import my_module
>>>
>>> assert my_dict == { "key": "default value" }
>>> assert my_module.my_dict == { "key": "default value" }
>>> assert my_str == "default string"
>>> assert my_module.my_str == "default string"
>>>
>>> my_dict["key"] = "new value"
>>> my_str = "new string"
>>>
>>> assert my_dict == { "key": "new value" }
>>> assert my_module.my_dict == { "key": "new value" }  # why did this change?
>>> assert my_str == "new string"
>>> assert my_module.my_str == "default string"  # why didn't this change?
>>>
>>> my_module.my_dict["key"] = "new value 2"
>>> my_module.my_str = "new string 2"
>>>
>>> assert my_dict == { "key": "new value 2" }  # why did this change?
>>> assert my_module.my_dict == { "key": "new value 2" }
>>> assert my_str == "new string"  # why didn't this change?
>>> assert my_module.my_str == "new string 2"
>>>
>>> my_dict = { "new_dict key" : "new_dict value" }
>>> assert my_dict == { "new_dict key": "new_dict value" }
>>> assert my_module.my_dict == { "key": "new value 2" }  # why didn't this change?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`my_module.my_str` refers to the `my_str` object in the `my_module` namespace, and modifying `my_module.my_str` modifies that object.

`from my_module import my_str` creates a `my_str` object in the local namespace, copied from the `my_module.my_str` object.  Modifying `my_str` modifies the object in the local namespace, but does not modify the `my_module.my_str` object.

`my_dict` is a reference in the local namespace to `my_module.my_dict`.  Because it's a reference to a mutable object (a dictionary), changes made to `my_dict` affect `my_module.my_dict` and vice versa.